# How to aggregate unique substrings in a column of strings in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `.csv` file as follows:

| Alphabet | Sub alphabet | Value | Strings |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 1 | AA, AB |
| A | C | 1 | AA, AC |
| A | E | 2 | AB, AD |
| A | F | 3 | AA, AD, AB |
| D | B | 1 | AB, AC, AD |
| D | C | 2 | AA, AD |
| D | E | 2 | AC, AD |
| D | F | 3 | AD |

```
Alphabet,Sub alphabet,Value,Strings
A,B,1,"AA, AB"
A,C,1,"AA, AC"
A,E,2,"AB, AD"
A,F,3,"AA, AD, AB"
D,B,1,"AB, AC, AD"
D,C,2,"AA, AD"
D,E,2,"AC, AD"
D,F,3,AD
```

I want it to return result like this:

| Alphabet | Value | Frequency | % | Strings |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 | 50% | AA, AB, AC, AD |
| A | 2 | 1 | 25% | AA, AB, AC, AD |
| A | 3 | 1 | 25% | AA, AB, AC, AD |
| D | 1 | 1 | 25% | AB, AC, AD, AA |
| D | 2 | 2 | 50% | AB, AC, AD, AA |
| D | 3 | 1 | 25% | AB, AC, AD, AA |

Believably expected table above is self-explanatory. The percentage refers to the corresponding row's frequency divided by total frequency. String refers to the string of the corresponding alphabet row.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
df = df.groupby(["Alphabet", "Value"], as_index=False).agg(Frequency=("Value", "count"))
df["%"] = df["Frequency"] / df.groupby("Alphabet")["Frequency"].transform("sum") * 100
df.to_csv("result.csv", index=None)
```

Feel free to leave a comment if you need more information.

How can I make such a .csv file? I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Markdown tables look nice, but they're hard to copy-and-paste. Maybe edit your question to show what your files look like? (This also appears to be using pandas, you might add the pandas tag).

Comment: Hi @AlexanderL.Hayes thanks for your comment! Sorry, I don't understand what "show what your files look like?" means. Question added `pandas` tag

Comment: CSV by convention uses comma delimiters, but there is a "Strings" column that contains commas. Pandas can sometimes handle this, or sometimes a different delimiter is used. Do you have CSV files? What do they look like?

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that the `Sub alphabet` column is not needed? Also, is the output`Strings` column the unique values in the input `Strings` column aggregated across the value in the `Alphabet` column only? So, you're really only having trouble with the `Strings` column then?

Comment: @frederick-douglas-pearce Yes, your understandings are correct for all. The `Sub alphabet` column is not needed, and the output `Strings` column are the unique values (non-duplication) in the input `Strings` column aggregated across the value in the Alphabet column.

Comment: Added a potential solution. May want to consider updating post title so it better describes the unique string aggregation problem you're asking about

Comment: Yes, please clarify what exactly you're asking, since you have at least some of it under control. See [ask]. See also [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/4518341)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the `Strings` column you'd like by splitting the string values on ', ', using `explode` to create separate rows for each unique value, and then selecting only the unique values with `drop_duplicates`:

```
import pandas as pd

df_inp = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
df_out = df_inp.groupby(["Alphabet", "Value"], as_index=False).agg(Frequency=("Value", "count"))
df_out["%"] = df_out["Frequency"] / df_out.groupby("Alphabet")["Frequency"].transform("sum") * 100

df_str_vals = df_inp[['Alphabet', 'Strings']].assign(str_vals=lambda x: x['Strings'].str.split(', ')).explode('str_vals').drop(columns='Strings').drop_duplicates()
```

Then you can use `groupby` to join the unique string values for each `Alphabet` value back together:

```
df_str_vals = df_str_vals.groupby(["Alphabet"], as_index=False)['str_vals'].apply(', '.join).rename(columns={'str_vals': 'Strings'})
```

leading to this result:

[image]

Finally, merge the `df_str_vals` dataframe back with your earlier result to obtain the `Strings` column for the output dataframe to write to the csv file:

```
df_out = df_out.merge(df_str_vals, on='Alphabet')
df_out.to_csv("result.csv", index=None)
```

[image]

Comment: Glad this solution worked for you. Again, it would be helpful if you could update the question title so it more accurately describes the question you had, e.g. "Aggregate unique substrings within a string column". That way others can benefit in the future.